# Improve runtime of an algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, nltk

I am studying the techniques of data mining and data processing. I'm doing this through data I've collected and stored in a csv file. The problem is that this filed was very large, to the point of having as astonishing 40 thousand lines of text.

Some of the algorithms in the rendering part are fast and agile, but the part of the orthographic correction of words is laborious. I am using the NLTK package `nltk.corpus import forest`. 
So when it comes time to do this step, I dare say it will not end in a timely manner.

From this, I was wondering if someone can help me with a solution where I can read a file line, do the whole process, save it to the bank and then read another line from the file. So by reading line by line and each line do the process. I think this way I can improve the performance of the algorithm.

Este é o meu código: (Please consider all the imports needed for the code to work)

```
txtCorpus = []
dtype_dic= {'status_id': str, 'status_message' : str, 'status_published':str}
for csvfile in pd.read_csv('data/AracajuAgoraNoticias_facebook_statuses.csv',dtype=dtype_dic,encoding='utf-8',sep=',', header='infer',engine='c', chunksize=2):
    txtCorpus.append(csvfile)

def status_processing(txtCorpus):

    myCorpus = preprocessing.PreProcessing()
    myCorpus.text = str(txtCorpus)

    print "Doing the Initial Process..."
    myCorpus.initial_processing()
    print "Done."
    print "----------------------------"

    print ("StartingLexical Diversity...")
    myCorpus.lexical_diversity()
    print "Done"
    print "----------------------------"

    print "Removing Stopwords..."
    myCorpus.stopwords()
    print "Done"
    print "----------------------------"

    print "Lemmatization..."
    myCorpus.lemmatization()
    print "Feito"
    print "----------------------------"

    print "Correcting the words..."
    myCorpus.spell_correct()
    print "Done"
    print "----------------------------"

    print "Untokenizing..."
    word_final = myCorpus.untokenizing()
    print "Feito"
    print "----------------------------"

    print "Saving in DB...."

    try:
        db.myDB.insert(word_final, continue_on_error=True)
    except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
        pass

    print "Insertion in the BB Completed. End of the Pre-Processing Process "


def main():
    status_processing(txtCorpus)

main()
```

I believe that by visualizing the code, you can better understand what I explained above. I thought about doing a `for` where I read a line and passed it on `def status_processing(txtCorpus):` and so, I repeated the process til the end. But I could not reach a solution.

Comment: Processing line by line probably won't make things faster. It will need less memory, though. But 40k lines of text doesn't sound that big, so that shouldn't cause problems. What's the size of the text (in characters/bytes)?

Comment: Try considering asking your question over [Here.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @lenz 30.657.186 bytes

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because improving working code is the domain of [codereview.se].

Comment: Sorry, I did not know this area existed here. I'm changing the topic there.